# Android View similar to Google's Youtube app?

Tags: java, android, view, android-layout, youtube

I know that Android's Youtube app is not open source, but I pulled apart the apk with apktool and found that they have a class, YoutubeListView used frequently in their app. Is there already an open source implementation of the Youtube Player Activity's title/ fling view/ layout? I know of similar views like Joao Machete's FlingAndScrollViewer, but I need it to be rigge to a title menu and work as smoothly as that on the Youtube app. If there is no open source implementation, either how hard would it be to convince Google to release just that component's source, or to implement it myself?

Thanks

Btw, the footer in this layout is what I am talking about. It has titles like Info & Related videos that can be clicked and it scrolls to them, and it can be scrolled left and right.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that there is no such view. It would be best to make my own custom layout.